# can the definite article ''the'' be omitted when describing a well-known evaluation metric

Tags: articles, usage

I wonder can the definite article ''the'' be omitted when describing a well-known evaluation metric?

> using average squared Euclidean distance as a measure of closeness

Source: https://drive.google.com/file/d/106d-rN7cXpyAkgrUqjcPONNCyO-rX7MQ/view

> F1 score is calculated from precision and recall values:

Source: https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.11.25.397729v2.full.pdf

> F1 score shows a clear trade-off between precision and recall

Source: https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41592-021-01141-3/MediaObjects/41592_2021_1141_MOESM1_ESM.pdf

In a paper, I want to describe precision, recall and (the) F1 score in a general way, but it doesn't look consistent if I don't use definite article for precision and recall (because they are uncountable) and suddenly give a definite article for F1 score (because score is countable). The sentence will looks like:

> Precision is defined as ..., recall as ..., and the F1 score as ....

Should I simply replace score with scores?

Comment: *Should I simply replace score with scores?* - NO. It's perfectly natural not to include any articles in ***Precision** is defined as ..., **recall** as ..., and **F1 score** as ...*

Comment: "using distance as a measure of closeness". The word "distance" is both countable and uncountable. It should be fine to omit the article. Next, in standard colloquial speech "F1 score" would be "the f1 score".  With the article. However in the context of a scientific paper such as this it's unclear.  Scientific papers often use stilted language. (the definite of that word seems to be "stiff, artificially formal or pompous".) So maybe they can omit the article and it's normal.